# Associating Objects and Users in Django using Generic Views

Tags: python, django, associations, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I'm attempting to associate a collection of Objects with a logged in user.

> Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('new/collection', views.CollectionCreate.as_view(), name="create"),
path('edit/collection/<int:pk>', views.CollectionUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
path('delete/collection/<int:pk>', views.CollectionDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

> Views.py

This page generates a form where a logged in `User` enters the title of the `Collection`, and creates it. As it is right now, the `Collection` does not get associated with any user. I know that this is the point in which I need to attach the created `Collection` to the logged in `User` but I have reached a stop point.

```
class CollectionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Collection
    template_name = 'upload/collection_form.html'
    fields = [
        'title'
    ]
```

> Models.py

In this class, a Collection is being associated with a default Django User.

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('gallery:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.author

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-upload_date']
```

Given a `form.ModelForm`, I know I can access the passed data by using `form = ModelForm(request.POST)` inside a `def post(self, ...)` function.

I don't know how to do that in a CreateView.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should customise the `get_form_kwargs` method.  `get_form_kwargs` gets all the arguments that are provided to the form, and one way to solve your problem is to inject the current user into the data provided to the form:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """
    Returns the keyword arguments for instantiating the form.
    """
    kwargs = {
        'initial': self.get_initial(),
        'prefix': self.get_prefix(),
    }

    # Add user to form kwargs
    data = self.request.POST.copy()
    data['user'] = self.request.user

    if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
        kwargs.update({
            'data': data,
            'files': self.request.FILES,
        })
    return kwargs
```

Comment: That looks like solid logic, although I'm confused by the initial and prefix keys in the kwargs dict. I'm also getting errors at the line where you are setting the 'user' key in data which is an immutable QueryDict from HttpRequest.

Comment: I think `initial` would be the form field "placeholder" values, `prefix` would be preprended to form element names/id's so they're ensured to be unique, probably helpful for pages with multiple forms. The immutable QueryDict can be worked around by calling `self.request.POST.copy()`, which I've amended in my answer.